# jQuery: Loop, find unique divs, and then append text from a value to a span

Tags: jquery, html

I've asked lots of questions about jQuery and have answered none, as I'm a beginner; I do know how to use jQuery to append CSS to a div, and add text to a div, and other easy things.

But, how does one go about this:

1) loop through a group of divs on a page that have unique IDs,

2) find the same div within and

3) append text from that one div to a second div?

There are answers on SO that do #2 and #3, but not that I could understand that handle #1.

Lame attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/e7nh01x4/

I have multiple instances of divs on a page with the structure below; each div has a random number appended to `acf-group_`  main div.

```
   <!-- unique div with random number-->
   <div id="acf-group_582920b45454f" class="postbox acf-postbox closed">

   <!-- append text to this div -->
   <h2 class="hndle ui-sortable-handle"><span>Existing Text</span></h2>

        <!-- other html -->

        <div class="acf-field acf-field-text acf-field-582920b45454f" data-name="link_text"
    data-type="text" data-key="field_582920b45454f" data-required="1">
        <div class="acf-label">
            <label for="acf-field_582920b45454f">Link Text
<span class="acf-required">*</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="acf-input">

           <!-- text value I want is in this div -->

            <div class="acf-input-wrap"><input id="acf-field_582920b45454f" class="" name="acf[field_582920b45454f]"
value="Text I Want" placeholder="" type="text"></div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <!-- other html -->

        </div>
```

What I want to do is grab the text value "Text I Want" from the input field `#acf-field_582920b45454f`.

Each of these outer divs with the classes `.acf-field .acf-field-text .acf-field-582920b45454f` also have the data-name `link_text`, and that data-name is unique among other divs inside the `#acf-group_582920b45454f` as a whole. This appears to be the key to locate the text value I need.

And then I want to append that text `Text I Want` inside the span after the existing text in `<h2 class="hndle ui-sortable-handle"><span>Existing Text</span>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want:

```
$('.acf-input-wrap > input').each(function() {
  $(this).closest('.acf-field.acf-field-text').prev('h2').find('span').append($(this).val())
})
```

```js
$('.acf-input-wrap > input').each(function() {
  $(this).closest('.acf-field.acf-field-text').prev('h2').find('span').append($(this).val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="acf-group_582920b45454f" class="postbox acf-postbox closed">

  <h2 class="hndle ui-sortable-handle"><span>Existing Text</span></h2>

  <div class="acf-field acf-field-text acf-field-582920b45454f" data-name="link_text" data-type="text" data-key="field_582920b45454f" data-required="1">
    <div class="acf-label">
      <label for="acf-field_582920b45454f">Link Text 1
        <span class="acf-required"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="acf-input">
      <div class="acf-input-wrap">
        <input id="acf-field_582920b45454f" class="" name="acf[field_582920b45454f]" value="Text I Want 1" placeholder="" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>


<div id="acf-group_5828d46a44c4b" class="postbox acf-postbox closed">

  <h2 class="hndle ui-sortable-handle"><span>Existing Text</span></h2>

  <div class="acf-field acf-field-text acf-field-5828d46a44c4b" data-name="link_text" data-type="text" data-key="field_5828d46a44c4b" data-required="1">
    <div class="acf-label">
      <label for="acf-field_5828d46a44c4b">Link Text 2
        <span class="acf-required"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="acf-input">
      <div class="acf-input-wrap">
        <input id="acf-field_5828d46a44c4b" class="" name="acf[field_5828d46a44c4b]" value="Text I Want 2" placeholder="" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="acf-group_5828d45828d46" class="postbox acf-postbox closed">

  <h2 class="hndle ui-sortable-handle"><span>Existing Text</span></h2>

  <div class="acf-field acf-field-text acf-field-5828d45828d46" data-name="link_text" data-type="text" data-key="field_5828d45828d46" data-required="1">
    <div class="acf-label">
      <label for="acf-field_5828d45828d46">Link Text 3
        <span class="acf-required"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="acf-input">
      <div class="acf-input-wrap">
        <input id="acf-field_5828d45828d46" class="" name="acf[field_5828d45828d46]" value="Text I Want 3" placeholder="" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Unless your HTML structure is vastly different from the example you provided, the key lies with locating your inputs which you can do with `$('.acf-input-wrap > input')` based on:

```
<div class="acf-input-wrap"><input id="acf-field_582920b45454f" class="" name="acf[field_582920b45454f]" value="Text I Want" placeholder="" type="text"></div>
```

Then you can loop over then via `.each()` and traversing to the span via `closest()`, `prev()`, and `find()`.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I want. That's cool. It works here in the snipper on SO, but I can't get it to work in the fiddle. Do I need a document ready?

Comment: No, by default jsFiddle wrap your code in a window onload event. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/e7nh01x4/1/

Comment: Ah, that works now. Thanks. Very compact for what it does. Now, hah, my next step is to get it to work in WordPress. No errors in the console, so should I be more specific with the outer div ID's? I.e., [id^=acf_group_] ?

Comment: You can try that. Also, I believe WP uses `jQuery` vs `$`

Comment: OK, I now have `jQuery('[id^=acf_group_] .acf-input-wrap > input').each(function() {
  jQuery(this).closest('.acf-field.acf-field-text').prev('h2').find('span').append($(this).val())
})`  I may have to fight with it myself, as WP has lots of overhead that must be conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each `<div>` and fetch/use the matchin ID:

```
$('[id^=acf-group_]').each(function() {
  var getIDnumber = $(this).attr('id').split('_').reverse()[0],
      textWanted = $('.acf-field-'+getIDnumber+' .acf-input-wrap input').val();
  $(this).find('h2').after('<div>'+textWanted+'</div>');
})
```

This will make sure that you will find the exact match based on the ID-number

Comment: Thanks, appears to be what I need, but I can't get it to work in the fiddle.

Comment: Sorry - first of all, there was a typo in the id-selector I used (a _ instead of a -), and there was a small fubar with the `append`-function. Fixed it and updated the code.

Comment: Cool, thanks, let me test it. This is for Wordpress and as such I've found some other issues with js overhead, etc. I also appended a div to the original target div, rather than append to the div as it had js click events attached to it which seemed to break things.